# How to access the content of Nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

For the above dictionary I am trying to iterate to access the values in my nested dictionary. I want to access `'Pos': (8.426625936328438, 8.734385941525895)`  key,value pair from nested dictionary, but I'm not able to access the nested dictionary values.

```py
(
    0,
    {
        'id': 0,
        'name': 0,
        'data': {
            'Mha': 'PHMA1',
            'Rack': '101',
            'RackNbr': 1,
            'HorCoor': '1',
            'VerCoor': 10,
            'Pos': (8.426625936328438, 9.387017518725838),
            'Type': 'pick'
        }
    }
)

(
    1,
    {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 1,
        'data': {
            'Mha': 'PHMA1',
            'Rack': '101',
            'RackNbr': 1,
            'HorCoor': '6',
            'VerCoor': 10,
            'Pos': (8.426625936328438, 8.734385941525895),
            'Type': 'pick'
        }
    }
)
```

Here's the code I tried:

```py
for id in NodeDict:
    print("Node Id", id)
        for key in NodeDict[id]:
            print(key + ':', NodeDict[id][key])
```

Output for what I tried:

```py
Node Id 0
id: 0
name: 0
data: {'Mha': 'PHMA1', 'Rack': '101', 'RackNbr': 1, 'HorCoor': '1', 'VerCoor': 10, 'Pos': (9.680053042990044, 10.65663364187665), 'Type': 'pick'}

Node Id 1
id: 1
name: 1
data: {'Mha': 'PHMA1', 'Rack': '101', 'RackNbr': 1, 'HorCoor': '6', 'VerCoor': 10, 'Pos': (9.680053042990044, 9.88930691075074), 'Type': 'pick'}
}]
```

But I want to access only Pos value. Can any one here help?

Comment: Your input does not appear to be valid data.

Comment: What about `NodeDict[id]['data']['Pos']`?

Comment: I am getting the values from another function so, i can't direclty access data and Pos, if am trying to do in this way NodeDict[id]['data']['Pos'] it is showing key error.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Nestes-lookup](https://pypi.org/project/nested-lookup/). That library will allow you to find all keys in dict much fastly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can access it directly after all.
I think your problem is the following:

You are getting a KeyError because you wrote something using just **id** like:

```
print(NodeDict[id]['data']['Pos'])
```

Write `NodeDict[0]['data']['Pos']` or `NodeDict[1]['data']['Pos']` instead and it should work. It should also work in a loop:

```
for id in NodeDict:
    NodeDict[id]['data']['Pos']
```

The error is caused because id() is a function and therefore **id** isn't highlighted as undefined when used as a key in the square brackets.

Answer (score -1):

Try rewriting your data, for example:

```
d = {}      
d[0] = {'id': 0, 'name': 0, 'data': {'Mha': 'PHMA1', 'Rack': '101', 'RackNbr': 1, 'HorCoor': '1', 'VerCoor': 10, 'Pos': (8.426625936328438, 9.387017518725838), 'Type': 'pick'}} 
d[1] = {'id': 1, 'name': 1, 'data': {'Mha': 'PHMA1', 'Rack': '101', 'RackNbr': 1, 'HorCoor': '6', 'VerCoor': 10, 'Pos': (8.426625936328438, 8.734385941525895), 'Type': 'pick'}}
```

then

```
> d[0]['data']['Pos']                                                                                  
> (8.426625936328438, 9.387017518725838)

> d[1]['data']['Pos']                                                                                  
> (8.426625936328438, 8.734385941525895)
```